# Is it possible to use BMX steerer (stem+handlebars) on fork on folding bicycle?

Tags: compatibility, bmx, folding-bicycle, steerer

II want to replace my folding bike's steerer with a BMX setup.

I've been told by a bike shop that it is not possible because the steerer tube protrudes 10 cm higher than the frame tube.

[image]

[image][image][image]

Comment: The last photo, it is not seen what type of handlebar your bike currently has. It will help if you provide a photo of it as well. Also, it is not 100% clear what is meant under "steerer tube protrudes 10 cm higher than the frame tube." The old steer tube protrudes, or the new one protrudes? Was it considered too much, or too little? Overall, your question is both about mechanical compatibility (is it can be done at all) and safety (will it be safe to ride with the new steerer). Were mechanic's concerns about the first, or the second point?

Comment: Hi Grigory, thanks for getting back to me. I’m not up with bike terms so I hope you can understand. What I’m wanting to do is completely remove the current folding tube and just attach the new bmx bars to the protruding steerer tube which will rise about 10cm from where my finger is pointing on the third image. One bike mech. Said it can’t be done and is unsafe. The second is saying it can’t be done.

Comment: To clarify - you want to change the stem and remove the folding joint, and install a stem that will be fixed ?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct

Comment: Assuming that the tube is the right diameter and you can arrange the bearings appropriately on it (both big assumptions) then you should be able to physically mount the bar on the tube.  If (as is likely the case) the tube is too short, one could jury-rig some sort of extension, though how robust this would be would be dependent on your cleverness.

Comment: did you ever get a solution to this? I'm looking to do the same thing.

Comment: @DavidBirch its been two years since this was asked.  Would you mind posting an answer showing how you got on, what needed to be done, and how it worked for you.

Answer (score 3):

There may be a compatibility problem with the BMX stem with the top bearing of the headset that would prevent it clamping the headset properly, however, I strongly suspect that the BMX bars would be far to low to be safe, and that's why thw bike mechanics wont touch it.